# error starting new thread in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start new thread when a function is called but it gives me

```
Android: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
```

here is my code

```
public class webcam_audio_record_V1_4 extends webcam_audio_record implements Command {

    private static final int TLV_EXTENSIONS = 20000;
    private static final int TLV_TYPE_AUDIO_DURATION = TLVPacket.TLV_META_TYPE_UINT | (TLV_EXTENSIONS + 1);
    private static final int TLV_TYPE_AUDIO_DATA = TLVPacket.TLV_META_TYPE_RAW | (TLV_EXTENSIONS + 2);

    public int execute(Meterpreter meterpreter, TLVPacket request, TLVPacket response) throws Exception {

        int duration = request.getIntValue(TLV_TYPE_AUDIO_DURATION);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { record(); } });
        thread.start();

        try { wait(duration * 1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        try { thread.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        play(); 
        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

    public void record() {
    }

    public void play() {
    }
```

how can i start a thread in android successfully

Comment: read the doc for the wait method. (which you probably did, didn't you, but still, read it again. it's all there.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're confusing `Object.wait()` with `Thread.sleep()`. `sleep()` is used to do nothing for some duration, and then wake up. `wait()` is used to wait for some condition to happen, and be awaken by another thread calling `notify()` or `notifyAll()`. And you must hold the monitor of the object on which you `wait()`.

Look up their javadoc to understand what they do and how to use them. `wait()` should generally be avoided anyway. You should use higher level abstrations like Semaphores instead.

Also, note that your code doesn't make much sense. You're staring a thread, and then block the current one waiting for the started thread to complete. You'd better do everything in the current thread. It would be simpler, clearer, and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

while using wait() use the following

```
    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
        lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
```

where

`Object lock = new Object();`

and while notifying use the same lock object

```
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notify();                  
    }
```

Comment: how nice of you to simplify and rephrase the doc like that. (no really, no sarcasms. I just don't see what's the point)

Comment: sorry if I did anything wrong. but many problems can be solved by just pointing to doc/links. Shouldn't we answer the exact point here? I am more active in so answering only from last week inspite I am having an old account so may be i misunderstood something.

Comment: the problem here is that Anwar Mohamed's question clearly show he has not read the documentation for the method he uses. He is not facing any problem other than that. Giving him the code that specifically solves the exception will not help him, as (as JB Nizet poited out), he clearly is misusing the wait method. Also, when a question is so basic it can be answered by A/ poiting to the doc or B/ poiting to an existing question, please do so.

Comment: ok .. thanks for the advice. From now on I will ty to follow it :)

Comment: i used wait here so that it keeps recording for some times btw